# WPF cancel drag operation

Tags: wpf, drag

How can i cancel a current drag operation? I want to use the escape key to cancel running drag operations.

Ive looked at the DragDrop class, but cant see anything that would achieve something like DragDrop.Cancel. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the cancelling operation using the following:

On the `Control` performing the drag (DataGrid in my case) I added a  handler for the `QueryContinueDrag` event.

```
private void DataGrid_QueryContinueDrag(object sender,
                                        QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
{
    if (... condition ...)
        e.Action = DragAction.Cancel;
}
```

The condition in your case would be `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Escape)`.

Comment: Or directly [`e.EscapePressed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.querycontinuedrageventargs.escapepressed.aspx).

Comment: Consider adding e.Handled=true below

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DragDrop.QueryContinue` event, this allows you to cancel it via the `Action` property.